# How to run batch file with credentials using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I've `mkdir` commands in a batch file but only admins have permissions to create directory, so how to pass credentials from Jenkins job to the batch file.

```
mkdir \\%%S.domain.com\c$\Test
```

Comment: Check out [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: But that prompts user to enter password, so how to configure it in Jenkins

Comment: Use one of the alternatives such as [this](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/53.htm) that allow you to specify the password on the command line. Use EnvInject / Mask Passwords plugins in Jenkins to store the password in Jenkins and hide it in the console output (alternatively, just `@echo off` in the batch build step).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Daniel, it might be done using such utility tools but my organization doesn't allow me to use third party tools without approvals. So, we have configured server with WinRM that allows to connect to server remotely using credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Select the "use secret text(s) or file(s) and then add a binding.  See screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Where do I find these settings?

Comment: Just to add to this, use the Bindings as above to store and pass the username and password.

The set the username variable to USERNAME and Password Variable to PASSWORD, then in you batch file use the `net use` command


    net use "\\server\share" %PASSWORD% /user:%USERNAME%
    \* whatever you need to do on that share, e.g. xcopy, mkdir *\
    net use "\\server\share" /delete

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Marc's answer, use the secret text Bindings as suggested to store and pass the username and password as environment variables.

The set the username variable to USERNAME and Password Variable to PASSWORD, then in your batch file use the `net use` command like so.

```
net use "\\server\share" %PASSWORD% /user:%USERNAME%
\* whatever you need to do on that share, e.g. xcopy, mkdir *\
net use "\\server\share" /delete
```